# php encode json correctly and use it with my special array

Tags: php, json, web, encoding

I've experienced a problem when developing for a minecraft server: I have an array like this which is received as `json` and encoded but for processing the output of this I need to know how to access the array and echo one of the values for Example the Version Key.I tried to save the array as variable `$json` and to access it via `echo $json->Version;` but this results in the output of this error: `Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/bs-web/joomla/api/test2.php on line 12`

Here´s the Array:

```
Array
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [GameName] => MINECRAFT
        [Version] => 1.8
        [Plugins] => 
        [Map] => BungeeCord_Proxy
        [Players] => 7
        [MaxPlayers] => 100
        [HostPort] => 25565
        [HostIp] => 188.40.97.86
        [Software] => Vanilla
    )
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `$json` is an array, you cannot get property of an array. Assuming you have only one element in the array as in your example, you should use

```
echo $json[0]->Version;
```

to display the version(`1.8` in your example).

Answer (score 0):

once you saves the `$json` variable as an array, you only can access its values passing the key that you want to use, and then, point to the object. In your case, to get the Version property, you will need to use `$json[0]->Version`.
To access and echo all values of your object you can use a foreach loop to iterate with it.

```
foreach ($json as $object){
    echo $object->GameName;
    echo $object->Version;
    echo $object->Plugins;
    .... // All properties that you want
}
```

Hope it helps you, hugs.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `json_decode($json, true)` then you get an assocative array which you can access like this `$json['Version']`